# Loop over object and display value into list based on option choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, for-loop

I have a constructor and have created some instances of it which I have placed in an array. What I am trying to do is to display the value of said object into the empty list depending on what I choose from a list of options. Here is what I have done so far:

```
<ul id="contactinfo"></ul>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="number">Phone Number</option>
</select>
```

```js
function ContactList (name, email, number) {
this.name = name;
this.email = email;
this.number = number;
}

var christian = new ContactList('Christian', 'christian@yahoo.com', '323-555-124');
var contactarray = [christian];

function displayinfo () {
    var dropdown = $('#dropdown').val();
    var number = $('#dropdown').val('number');
    var email = $('#dropdown').val('email');

    for (i = 0; i < contactarray.length; i++) {
        if (dropdown == number) {
            $('#contactinfo').append('<li>' + contactarray[i].number + '</li>');
        } else {
            $('#contactinfo').append('<li>' + contactarray[i].email + '</li>');
        }
    }
}

displayinfo();
```

Comment: so you want to display the info from the object depending on what is selected in the drop down? Is `#contacts` supposed to be `#contactinfo`?

Comment: yes sorry that was a mistake, made the edit

Comment: can you include you code of `ContactList`?

Comment: here you go, made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that the main issue with your current code is that `$('#dropdown').val()`, `$('#dropdown').val('number')` and `$('#dropdown').val('email')` all return the same thing - the dropdown in a jQuery object. Also note the latter two are also setting the value to that provided, so the JS would always only retrieve the `email` as that was what is set last.

To fix it, you can take the value selected in the dropdown and retrieve that property from the `contactarray` element directly. Try this:

```
function displayinfo () {
    var $contacts = $('#contactinfo').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < contactarray.length; i++) {
        $contacts.append('<li>' + contactarray[i][$('#dropdown').val()] + '</li>');
    }
}
```

Finally, you also need to execute `displayinfo` when the option in the select is changed, and also clear out any previously appended `li`. Check out the fiddle below for a full working example:

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLqnnvj9/)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out I can see where the mistake is with the drop down variable, so what would be the correct syntax to select the value of a option?

Comment: If you want to *set* the selected option, use `.val('email')`, to *get* the value, use `.val()`. More info: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: ok that makes sense, also how does contactarray[i][$('#dropdown').val()] get the specific value from the object, is it because the option values have the same name as the properties? (sorry for all the question, just trying to understand)

Comment: It's accessing the object contained in `contactarray[i]` using bracket notation. It's equivalent to `contactarray[i].email` for example (assuming 'email' was chosen in the dropdown)

Comment: if the option values where different however, how would you adjust the code to implement the change?

Comment: If the option values were different to the property names of the `ContactList` object then you'd need to use an `if` statement as your original code did.